# How to Create Contact in Google inside a group

Tags: java, gdata, google-contacts-api

Can any body tell me how i can create a google contact under the group like i have one group by name family under this i want to add the contact. Now i am able to create contact but its going under others following code i am using

```
ContactEntry contact = new ContactEntry();
contact.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct("chetan"));
contact.setContent(new PlainTextConstruct("sharma"));

Email primaryMail = new Email();
primaryMail.setAddress("newcontact@gmail.com");
primaryMail.setRel("http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home");
primaryMail.setPrimary(true);
contact.addEmailAddress(primaryMail);

ExtendedProperty favouriteFlower = new ExtendedProperty();
favouriteFlower.setName("favourite flower");
favouriteFlower.setValue("daisy");
contact.addExtendedProperty(favouriteFlower);


//URL postUrl = new URL("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/defaults/full");
contact = service.insert(feedUrl, contact);
GroupMembershipInfo groupMembershipInfo = new GroupMembershipInfo(false, "http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/defaults/base/39eb8f59897bac4d");
//groupMembershipInfo
contact.addGroupMembershipInfo(groupMembershipInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are inserting the contact before adding the groupMembershipInfo. If you want to add the group membership details to the contact, move this line "contact = service.insert(feedUrl, contact);" as a last line of the code.

You can refer to this [page](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#updating_contacts) for more details.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can execute below method and get Atom id for different groups in your account like My Contacts, Family etc.

```
public static void printAllGroups(ContactsService myService)
        throws ServiceException, IOException {
      // Request the feed
      URL feedUrl = new URL("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/ankit.ab2502@gmail.com/full");
      ContactGroupFeed resultFeed = myService.getFeed(feedUrl, ContactGroupFeed.class);

      for (ContactGroupEntry groupEntry : resultFeed.getEntries()) {
        System.out.println("Atom Id: " + groupEntry.getId());
        System.out.println("Group Name: " + groupEntry.getTitle().getPlainText());
      }
}
```

Output of this method for Family group will be like:

Atom Id: http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/UR_EMAIL_ID/base/e

Use this url to add contact to a Family group

```
 GroupMembershipInfo groupMembershipInfo = new GroupMembershipInfo(false, "http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/UR_EMAIL_ID/base/e");
                 contact.addGroupMembershipInfo(groupMembershipInfo);
```